# get contents height of div that has oveflow:hidden style

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm designing a vertical scroll-bar plugin for jquery. my plugin accepts a **height** value as option and if the div height exceeds the given height the scroll-bar will be visible. now the problem is I need to get the real height of the div content.

```
  <div id="scroll">
     Contents Here
    </div>
```

jquery:

```
 $.fn.vscrollbar = function (options) {
    .
    .
    .
    var contentHeight=this.contents().height() //that is not working correctly
    if(contentHeight > options.height){
    this.css({overflow : 'hidden'}).height(options.height); 
    }
    .
    .
    .
    })(jQuery);
```

I can get the height of div before applying 'overflow:hidden' but the problem is I want this to work even if it has overflow:hidden style from the begining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a hidden `div` on the page, of the same `width` but `overflow auto`. As soon as your plugin is called/instantiated, take the height of that hidden `div` and do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

One way I know should work is having a content element inside of the overflow and get the height of that since it should retain its height value.

Answer (score 0):

The .css() method should work

```
$(this).css('height');
```

Comment: this wouldn't work as i'm setting the height to be options.height. it will return options.height not the content height.